# preg_replace php замена по очереди

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Исходный код:

```
[display = "home"]
    html code
[/display]
[display = "category"]
    html code
[/display]
[display = "home"]
    html code
[/display]
```

Подскажите, как написать регулярное выражение, что бы шорт-код например `[display = "home"]...[/display]` заменялся на пустоту. Главное, что бы он заменялся по очереди. То есть регулярное выражение должно находить начало `[display = "..."]...` и первый найденный `[/display]`, а не последний. Старался описать понятно.

Делаю так в цикле, но результат плох:

```
$pattern = str_replace(["\"", "[", "]", " ", "/"], ["\\\"", "\[", "\]", "\s+", "\/"], $display[1][$key]);
$pattern2 = str_replace(["\"", "[", "]", " ", "/"], ["\\\"", "\[", "\]", "\s+", "\/"], $display[4][$key]);

$result = preg_replace('/'.$pattern.'(.+?)'.$pattern2.'/is', "", $result);
```

Где в `$pattern` попадает `\[display = \"home\"\]`, а в `$pattern2` попадает `\[\/display\]` но в итоге результат не тот, который ожидается.

Comment: Такой результат ожидается? [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a3f50e842ef846a5c130af9cb73e6fd39171f353)

Comment: ожидается заменить например второй шорт-код и все что в нем хранится пустотой, а в вашем случае выводится просто первый шорт код с внутренним кодом. Но я возможно не правильно понял Ваш код.

Comment: @Эдуард да, сразу не понял. Ваш вариант работает, но не пойму как мне его написать в моем случае.

Comment: @Эдуард по коду `/\[display\s+=\s+\"category\"\]([^[]+)\[\/display\]/U` у меня везде все нормально, но на главное странице, когда = home, вылазит это `[display = "category"]`, трудно описать словами.

Comment: Да, верно. В переменной хранится тип страницы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85470/discussion-between--and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам регулярка для шаблонизатора:

```
/\[display = "(.+)"\]([^[]+)\[\/display\]/U
```

Если использовать `preg_replace_callback` можно на лету менять содержимое или вовсе убирать блоки.
Пример работы регулярки: https://regex101.com/r/WlkqLp/1/

```
$regExp = '/\[display = "(.+)"\]([^[]+)\[\/display\]/U';
preg_replace_callback($regExp,function ($matches)
  {
    if($matches[1]=='home') return '';
    if($matches[1]=='category') return $matches[2];
  },$value);
```

Comment: @Эдуард уже более менее лучше, но все вокруг да около. Извините, тут нельзя скайп попросить для помощи online ?

Comment: @Эдуард и что не так? регулярка не жадная и выбирает именно то что просил автор, даже написано как именно использовать в его целях, а теперь еще и дополнено примером....

Comment: @Владимир обновите ответ, я его дополнил, и нет смысла в скайпе... можем перейти в чат для обсуждения если очень надо =)

Comment: Что вы говорите? вы пример использования смотрели? если он вам непонятен - так и скажите, регулярка именно для preg_replace_callback с возможностью анализа внутри пользовательской функции найденых блоков. в примере например будут удалены блоки с display=home но при этом выведено содержимое блока display=category

Comment: Да, с модификатором `m` промазал, изначально(в примере по ссылке был верный), заменил на нужный

Comment: `g` почитайте ман по regex для php :) `g` в php не поддерживается ))

Comment: Ребята, спасибо большое, я пока не понимаю все же как сделать, ничего не выходит у меня и в чат я бы перешел, но не знаю как.

Comment: @Владимир спасибо Эдуарду за песочницу, вот пример как это использовать http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/52228b0a6de3c938c6bd3419ccc9c1a7ed04a50c
Для чата - надо попросить модератора создать оный =) у меня пока что недостаточно прав на создание чата в комментариях
Про `g` - в php и без него прекрасно будет работать, и он ничуть не мешает там, но если он не работает в php,что скорей всего так и есть, он там и не мешает =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков вот зачем вы вводите в заблуждение человека? ) Написано же __модификатор g не поддерживается__ - значит работать не будет: `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'`

Comment: Спасибо, проблема оказывается была в `(.+?)` в моем коде, а нужно было `([^[]+)`

Comment: Тогда вам хватило бы квантификатора `U` чтоб захват был не жадным или вместо`+` использовать `*`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков `U` - это квантификатор?